# Drop-Down Menu Transparency Won't Work

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal 7's premium responsive theme, and I cannot seem to make the drop-down transparency work. I have used both methods of making items transparent and neither worked.

1st -

```css
#main-menu li li a,
#main-menu li li a:link,
#main-menu li li a:visited {
    background-color: none;
    background: rgb(0, 16, 38);
    background: rgba(0, 16, 38, 0.75);
    border-top-width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 85px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

2nd - made a transparent image in photoshop

```css
#main-menu li li a,
#main-menu li li a:link,
#main-menu li li a:visited {
    background-color: none;
    background-image: url('images/transparent.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 85px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

For some reason I cannot remove the background color through my css, even with background set to none (yes I have tried deleting it completely, using !important, and transparent).

I think part of the problem is that the actual base theme won't let you have the sub-menu background color be equal to nothing, yet I have searched through the php and haven't been able to find anything that would be declaring the background to grab a default color. Any thoughts?

Here is a screenshot
[image: Menu Transparency Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried applying !important to the background?

Comment: What does the Firefox > DOM Inspector > Computed Style tab say about the elements?

Comment: That's the thing, it says that there is no color assigned to the drop-down portion of the menu. It seems to be inheriting the color from the parent menu for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a live link @Jeff

Comment: There's a js-enabled class on there. Is Javascript overriding your CSS?

Comment: No, that is just for mouse-over and mouse-out delays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inspector in Chrome I've added in the following style:

```
#main-menu li ul li a {
    background: red !important;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This has changed the sub nav items for me. It looks like you're missing the ul in the selectors. Try changing it to this:

```
#main-menu li ul li a,
#main-menu li ul li a:link,
#main-menu li ul li a:visited {
    background: rgb(0, 16, 38);
    background: rgba(0, 16, 38, 0.75);
    border-top-width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 85px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: That's working properly, but I still get no transparency because there is a background that cannot be removed for some reason. I'll attach a screen shot to my question. (upvote for your help)

Comment: OK I'm about to leave my desk for the day but try removing background-color completely.

Comment: Also try running through the css for #12263B. That's the color, so if you are really stuck remove each instance till it's gone, but I think removing background-color should do the trick for you.

Comment: alright, I'll try that. Thanks, I really appreciate your help. This has been a minor but frustrating problem ha

Comment: Do you use the inspector in Chrome? It's an invaluable tool.

Comment: No I've been using firefox, maybe I should switch over to that. But I found the solution. I'll post the answer

Comment: God yes! Chrome is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **transparent** color for the `background-color`:

```
 background-color: transparent;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Cr2br/)**

---

Valid values for this property are:

- a color
- transparent
- inherit

[Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-color)

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in the question as well, but I did try transparent, inherit, and !important and nothing worked. I have been searching through the php to see if the menus are pulling anything specific but I cannot find anything

Comment: Check you don't have a more specific css selector that would take over inherirance. You best bet is to check the console (F12) and see by yourself the css inheritance.

Comment: Not live, unfortunately I am on a test server. I think the problem is with the base theme though. If you have drupal on your computer, the theme is premium responsive

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of time (and a lot of help from you guys @spacebeers & didier ghys) I figured out the solution.

There was a php file called colors.inc that was overriding all of the colors on the site. It was hidden in the folder and marked improperly so that is why I missed it. I literally deleted the entire file so it gave me free range on all of the colors. I then used spacebeers code above and it worked like a charm. Here is the new screenshot:

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thanks again @spacebeers. I'll accept your answer since it helped me reach my solution.